# How to set Git branch protected in GitHub by default when create it

Tags: github, automation

I need to make a branch protected directly when creating it. I know that I need to go to Settings and set it as protected from there, but what I'm looking for is to set the branch as protected automatically without the need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub doesn't have a way to natively enable branch protection for new branches. However, you could set up an automated process using "Update branch protection" from the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#update-branch-protection) to add branch protection to all new branches.

> `PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch/protection`